# Polygon edge gradient algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graphics, polygon, gradient

I'm trying to create an application that uses an uncommon polygon gradient fill. The idea is that each edge of the polygon has a single colour, and these edge colours are used to fill the rest of the polygon's pixels in a smooth gradient.

I have a working program that performs this gradient by determining, for each pixel, how far it is from all the polygon's edges and doing a weighted average of all the edges' colours based on the distances to them. Here's a sample output:

[image: Polygon edge gradient sample (click link to view)]

The problem is that the algorithm is horribly slow when the polygon has a lot of edges, namely because for every single pixel, it has to calculate distances to every edge. Any ideas for how this could be sped up?

Current algorithm:

```
for pixel in polygon: # predetermined using a basic scan-line polygon-fill algorithm
    edge_distances = {}
    for edge in polygon:
        distance = calc_point_to_line_distance(pixel, edge) # simple formula, constant time            
        edge_distances[edge] = distance
    colour = calc_pixel_colour(edge_distances)  # runs in O(num_edges) time
    set_pixel_colour(pixel, colour)
```

I've left out the details because I'm looking for big picture ideas of how to do this better (i.e. better than `O(num_pixels*num_edges)`). All ideas welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to optimize an algorithm we can't see.  If you want help, you will have to share some code.

Comment: Pseudocode added above.

Comment: Do you need to support concave polygons, or only convex ones?

Comment: Concave polygons, as well as polygons with holes.

Comment: Take a look at [Diffusion Curves](http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2008/OBWBTS08/).

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle Thanks, this is similar to what I want to do, although the math is beyond me, particularly the Jacobi / Poisson / Laplace equation stuff. I dug around for some code examples but everything I found was very high-level. If you had some specific code examples that you could point me to, that would be fantastic.

Comment: How many pixels / edges and what kind of *horribly slow* are we talking about? Since this is a global interpolation scheme, you can probably not do too much. There is probably more potential in the actual implementation (memory access etc.)

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid the math behind diffusion curves is quite involved. There are a couple of implementations, with code, at the link I provided. At least one of them GPU-based.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @SirRaffleBuffle for pointing me towards the answer (sorry, I don't have enough "reputation points" to upvote you).

What I went with in the end was a colour diffusion algorithm, combined with a multi-grid solver for massive performance gains (described mathematically [here](http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2008/OBWBTS08/), [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/reves/Basilic/2012/BB12/GradientArt.pdf), and [here](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/gradient-paint/grad.light.r2226.pdf); warning, lots of opaque math jargon and Greek letters).

The diffusion algorithm is fairly straightforward. You start with a canvas of pixels where some of them have specified colours (e.g. specified by you). Then, you start spreading the colours throughout the rest of the canvas by, for each pixel, averaging the four adjacent (non-diagonal) pixels. You then repeat this process over and over until all the pixels are filled and their colours stabilize.

This process is pretty slow in itself, but can be dramatically sped up with a "multi-grid solver." Here, you initially run the diffusion on a very small canvas (i.e. low resolution), then map the output colours to a second canvas with double the resolution, and run the diffusion on this canvas. This process can be repeated at higher and higher resolutions until you get what you want. The idea is to initialize the diffusion process with pixel colours that are close to the final output, thus cutting through most of the algorithm's work.

This is a pretty crude explanation; let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you. I've always thought the results of diffusion were very pleasing. You deserve reputation points yourself for providing such a nice non-mathematical explanation of the diffusion approach.

Comment: On the first iteration, after specifying some colours, how do we ignore non-initialised pixels? Otherwise, it would seem to me like it would mostly converge to the initial background colour (black or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The distance calculation is easy to optimize: the distance(x,y, edge_i) - distance(x+A,y+B, edge_i) is constant. This part of the algorithm can be reduced to single addition per pixel per edge. Further optimizations  (if any) depend on the pixel color determining function.

Comment: Interesting idea. But unless my calculations are wrong, this only seems to be true when the shortest line between the pixel and the edge is perpendicular to the edge. ([Diagram here -- red lines are perpendicular.](https://imgur.com/FSpg5z8)) That said, this could offer some optimization -- I'll look into it.

Comment: Consider an endpoint of one of your edges centered at a pixel center. Now calculate the perp dist from the center of each of the 8 neighboring pixels to the edge. These are the updates you need in moving from pixel to pixel.

Comment: There’s surprisingly little to calculate, since the gradient for x increment is simply -dy of the edge, and dx=x1-x0 for y-increment. But as stated, this applies to (orthogonal) distance to the infinite extension of any line segment and not to minimum distance to edge & vertex.